# PHP Protect property cannot be public but needed in Test

Tags: php, phpunit

In Result class, I must have a protected property $message, but when I run the code test in Maintest.php file, I can read the "successfully added set" message string inside the object, but because it is protected, I can't assert it against the actual object.
I cannot make it public.

Please check the inline comments and ask me anything if you need more information

```
// Result.php

class Result
{   
    protected $message = ""; // must be protected

    static function success($message='')
    {
        return new Result ( 0, $message );
    }

    private function __construct( $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }


    public function getMessage(){
            return $message;
    }

}
```

Model.php

```
function addNewNavDbSet($set){
    $set = ModelSet::init($set["name"],$set["visibility"],$set["name"],$set["info"]);
    $this->ModelDbProvider->addNewSet($set);
    $this->getResult('Succesfully added Set');
    return Result::success ('Succesfully added Set'); // cannot access protected property, but I cannot make it public
}


function getResult($message) {
        return $message;
}
```

MainTest.php

```
class MainNavTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{


    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Model = new Model();
    }


    public function testSaveProperty()
    {
        $mySet = $this->Model->addNewSet("test ADD", 1,"hello world", "test", '1');
        var_dump($mySet); // returns object with string 'succesfully added set'.
        var_dump(Result::getMessage());
        $this->assertStringContainsString('Succesfully added Set', Result::getMessage());

    }
}
```

/tests/application/models/MainTest.php

Error: Call to undefined method MainNavTest::assertStringContainsString()

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Comment: Then you need to write a GETTER method for that property

Comment: ___NOTE___ This line is missing something which shoudl really be throwing you an error:) `$this->assertStringContainsString('Succesfully added Set', $mySet->message;`

Comment: I am a little confused, `protected $message = ""; // must be private` this is  `protected` is not `private`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for hint. Will edit and fix it. The question is what the title is about.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I meant must continue protected, but I need to access it in MainTest.php to assert the object.

Comment: Then read the first comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly I fixed the typos and I also tried that but I failed because I don't know how to do it. Can you provide an answer? I will be happy to accept it from you. Please check my profile, you will understand.

Comment: Read about mocks or test doubles. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-getters-and-setters-methods-in-php

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the Getter function in Results.php, where $message property is avaiilable, but in the main test file, because they are separate files, I get Error: Call to undefined method Result::getMesssage()

Comment: `Result::getMesssage()` ? Did you make the method STATIC? I dont see that in the code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am updating the question. Error: Call to undefined method MainNavTest::assertStringContainsString()

Comment: `return $this->message;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for pacience, Error: Using $this when not in object context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233665/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-staminna).

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of:

> Error: Call to undefined method MainNavTest::assertStringContainsString()

IIRC the removal of:

```
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->Model = new Model();
    }
```

from the test-case should succeed.

The method is normally part of Phpunit, see [Assertions in the Phpunit Manual](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html)

And do not re-introduce *any* `__construct()`  method in your test-cases.

If you do not want to do the set-up in the concrete test-case method, use a fitting hook method, e.g. `setUp` I'll guess in your case:

```
    function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Model = new Model();
    }
```

See [Fixtures in the Phpunit Manual](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html).